# Deleting Records Based on Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I have a list of users (Field = UserName) that I got from a table (Users). Some are duplicates.

Where there is a duplicate record, I need to delete the most current record (CreatedOn) created.

Also, if it trips up on the ability to delete because there are 'relationships established to this user ID' in the database, I need it to skip to the next record and continue deleting.

How do I accomplish this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding on from Diego's answer with a check that the UserName is not the oldest instance in the table.

```
DELETE FROM 
    Users
WHERE 
    UserName IN 
    (SELECT UserName FROM Users GROUP BY UserName HAVING COUNT(UserName) > 1)
    AND
    CreatedOn != 
    (SELECT MIN(CreatedOn) FROM Users T1 WHERE UserName = T1.UserName);
```

Comment: That will delete duplicates including the record he want to keep.

Comment: The last two lines of code will avoid deleting the original by ensuring that only matching UserName records with a date that is different to the oldest entry is deleted. The original (oldest) would be kept.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Delete from Users
 where nameuser in 
(select nameuser from Users
Group by nameuser
Having count(nameuser) > 1)
```

Comment: Will remove all instances of a duplicated name. But one is supposed to be kept.

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS` to remove a row if same UserName also has an older CreatedOn:

```
delete from users u1
where exists (select 1 from users u2
              where u2.UserName = u1.UserName
                and u2.CreatedOn < u1.CreatedOn)
```

Or, another approach:

```
delete from users
where (UserName, CreatedOn) not in (select UserName, MIN(CreatedOn)
                                    from users
                                    group by UserName)
```

Comment: The first one won't work since it will delete every record that doesn't have a duplicate.  The second one will work only incase there could be only 1 duplicate, but lets say there are 3 records with same ID, it won't work.

Comment: Oops, thanks... What was I thinking... Need more coffee soon, will first edit!

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE  from  user u
WHERE   u.UserId in ( SELECT Distinct userid from User u join User u2 where u.UserName = u2.UserName
and u.CreatedOn > u2.CreatedOn)
```

You can't skip on error in one sql, but you could exclude userid that exists in related tables.